# Why is this data not correctly passing from parent component to child component, in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, parent-child

I have a vue component responsible for pagination, so that only 20 items are shown per page.  Everything is working except for the one value that I need passed down from the parent component, the 'count' value that returns the total number of items.

I use the 'count' value to calculate whether the "Next Page" button is active or not and what the total number of pages should be.  Using console.log I can see that the 'count' value returns correctly in to the parent component, but it always comes back as undefined in the child pagination component.  Please advise how I can fix this.

(I'm not sure if using watch here is correct; I thought it would solve the problem, but it changed nothing.)

**EDIT**: I've posted more of both the child and parent component for better context.

Here is the script of the child component:

```
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Pagination',
    props: ['count'],
    watch: {
      count: function (val, oldVal) {}
    },
    data () {
      return {
        currentPage: 1,
        limit: 20,
        paginationVisible: true,
        firstPageIsCurrent: true,
        prevEllipsisVisible: false,
        pageLink1: 2,
        pageLink1Visible: true,
        pageLink1IsCurrent: false,
        pageLink2: 3,
        pageLink2Visible: true,
        pageLink2IsCurrent: false,
        pageLink3: 4,
        pageLink3Visible: true,
        pageLink3IsCurrent: false,
        nextEllipsisVisible: true,
        lastPageVisible: true,
        lastPageIsCurrent: false,
        prevDisabled: true,
        nextDisabled: false,
        lastPage: 1
      }
    },
    methods: {
      handlePrev () {
        if (!this.prevDisabled) {
          this.currentPage -= 1
          this.paginate()
        }
      },
      handleNext () {
        if ((this.currentPage * this.limit) < this.count) {
          this.currentPage += 1
          this.paginate()
        }
      },
      handleFirstPage () {
        if (this.currentPage !== 1) {
          this.currentPage = 1
          this.paginate()
        }
      },
      handlePageLink1 () {
        if (this.currentPage !== this.pageLink1) {
          this.currentPage = this.pageLink1
          this.paginate()
        }
      },
      handlePageLink2 () {
        if (this.currentPage !== this.pageLink2) {
          this.currentPage = this.pageLink2
          this.paginate()
        }
      },
      handlePageLink3 () {
        if (this.currentPage !== this.pageLink3) {
          this.currentPage = this.pageLink3
          this.paginate()
        }
      },
      handleLastPage () {
        if (this.currentPage < this.lastPage) {
          this.currentPage = this.lastPage
          this.paginate()
        }
      },
      paginateAdjust () {
        console.log(this.count)
        // adjust pagination bar and previous/next buttons
        this.nextDisabled = ((this.currentPage * this.limit) >= this.count)
        this.prevDisabled = (this.currentPage === 1)
        const pageCount = Math.ceil(this.count / this.limit)
        // console.log(pageCount + ', cp: ' + this.currentPage)
        if (pageCount === 1) {
          this.paginationVisible = false
        } else {
          this.paginationVisible = true
          // first page link
          this.firstPageIsCurrent = this.currentPage === 1
          // previous ellipsis
          this.prevEllipsisVisible = this.currentPage > 3 && pageCount > 5
          // first page link
          this.pageLink2Visible = pageCount > 2
          if (this.currentPage < 4) {
            this.pageLink1 = 2
          } else if ((pageCount - this.currentPage) < 3) {
            this.pageLink1 = pageCount - 3
          } else {
            this.pageLink1 = this.currentPage - 1
          }
          this.pageLink1IsCurrent = this.pageLink1 === this.currentPage
          // second page link
          this.pageLink2Visible = pageCount > 3
          if (this.currentPage < 4) {
            this.pageLink2 = 3
           } else if ((pageCount - this.currentPage) < 3) {
            this.pageLink2 = pageCount - 2
          } else {
            this.pageLink2 = this.currentPage
          }
           this.pageLink2IsCurrent = this.pageLink2 === this.currentPage
          // third page link
          this.pageLink3Visible = pageCount > 4
          if (this.currentPage < 4) {
            this.pageLink3 = 4
          } else if ((pageCount - this.currentPage) < 3) {
            this.pageLink3 = pageCount - 1
          } else {
            this.pageLink3 = this.currentPage + 1
          }
          this.pageLink3IsCurrent = this.pageLink3 === this.currentPage
          // next ellipsis
          this.nextEllipsisVisible = ((pageCount - this.currentPage) >= 3) && pageCount > 5
          // last page
          this.lastPage = pageCount
          this.lastPageIsCurrent = this.currentPage === pageCount
        }
      },
      emitMSQ () {
        this.$emit('msq', this.currentPage, this.limit)
      },
      paginate () {
        this.paginateAdjust()
        this.emitMSQ()
      }
    },
    created () {
      this.paginate()
    }
  }
</script>
```

Here is the (relevant) script from the parent component:

```
export default {
  name: 'index',
  components: {Pagination},
  computed: {
    apps () {
      return this.$store.state.apps
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      apps: [],
      count: 0,
      searchAddress: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onSearch () {
      if (this.searchAddress.length === 12 || this.searchAddress.length === 0) {
        this.currentPage = 1
        this.makeServerQuery()
      }
    },
    makeServerQuery (cp, pp) {
      let queryStr = '?uid=' + this.$auth.user().id + '&cp=' + cp + '&pp=' + pp
      if (this.searchAddress.length === 12) {
        queryStr += '&se=' + this.searchAddress
      }
      this.$http.get('/apps' + queryStr).then(res => {
        this.apps = res.data.apps
        this.count = res.data.count
        console.log(this.count + ' msq()')
      })
    },
```

The emit, server query, and actual pagination elements all work fine. But my next page button is wrong and the last page button displays `NaN` because it can't run the correct calculations when `count === undefined`.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Can you show the template where you pass `count`?

Comment: Your `watch` is doing nothing, it can be removed. Can you please show how you are passing your count prop from the parent to the child? Also, it would help if you provide a minimal example of what the parent and child components look like.

Comment: @dan count is not being used in the template directly, it is being used in the paginate method of the child component.

Comment: @DanielOrmeño  I will show more of the code.  Give me just a moment to update.

Comment: The parent template is the one of interest, you must pass the prop there, so that's what we'd need to see.  If you haven't done that, that's the problem.  The parent has to pass the prop to the child in the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, it looks like you are not really passing anything to your component's prop.

As @Dan suggested, your `count` prop is `undefined` because nothing is being passed to it from the parent. To pass the `count` data property from the parent to the child you need to use a template binding `<child v-bind:count="count"></child>` or its shorthand `<child :count="count"></child>`.

The [official documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props) is a good starting point for understanding props.

Here's a minimal example.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.component('child', {
  template: `
  <div class="child">
    from parent: {{count}}
    <br>
    <button :disabled="!enableNext" @click="onNext">Next</button>
  </div>
  `,
  props: ['count'],
  computed: {
    enableNext() {
      return this.count && this.count > 0;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onNext() {
      console.log('Go to page ' + this.count + 1)
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: `
    <div class="parent">
      Parent count: {{ count }}
      <child :count="count" />
      <br>
      <button @click="count++">Increment count</button>
    </div>
  `,
  data:() => ({
    count: 0
  })
});
```

```css
div { border: solid 1px black; padding: 1em; }
.child { background: lightgray; }
button:disabled, button[disabled]{
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  color: #666666;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid quetion, Vue is still new to me.  I still need to do somehting like this:   from parent: {{count}}
in the child template, even if I'm not using the data in the template?   All I need is the value in to be accessible by the methods in the child component.

Comment: There's no stupid questions! To make data from the parent accesible to the child component you need to pass it on the template. Think of it as the `input` to the component. In the child, you declare the prop as a input variable, then the parent needs to "pass" the value into the child through the template `<Pagination  :count="count"></Pagination>`

Comment: @Brian I added a link to the documentation which should be helpful for understanding props

Comment: That fixed it.  Thank you!